# What extension for underlining html <tag> in visual studio code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need something like this (i have in bracket editor) but I don't know its come from which extension.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a extension for that.
Simply search for "**highlight-matching-tag**" in the extension tab

or download it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

I recommend to set a custom setting like this:

```
    "highlight-matching-tag.style": {
    "borderWidth": "1px",
    "borderColor": "orange",
    "borderStyle": "solid"
}
```